# Recording compressed Kinect data

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

I'm working with a new Kinect v2 sensor, and using Kinect Studio to record the Kinect stream data during some experiments. The problem is our experiments are expected to last ~10 minutes, which including the uncompressed video would be equivalent to ~80gb. In addition, the buffer fills up quite fast and around 2 minutes in and the remainder of the data ends up stuttering at around 2fps instead of the smooth 25fps.

Is there any way I can record all the data I need in compressed form? Would it be easy to create an app similar to kinect studio that just prints out a video file and a .xed file containing all the other sensor data?

Answer (score 1):

Kinect Studio [does have APIs](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59c97d1e-79f6-4dd0-8fae-73080a2c7b18/documentation-for-microsoftkinecttools-api?forum=kinectv2sdk) that can be used to programmatically record particular data streams into an XEF file. Additionally, it's possible to have multiple applications using the sensor simultaneously, so in theory you should be able to have three applications collecting data from the sensor (you could combine these into one application as well):

1. Your application;
2. An application using the Kinect Studio APIs, or Kinect Studio itself, to record the non-RGB streams;
3. Another application that collects the RGB data stream and performs compression and then saves the data.

However, the latency and buffer issue is likely to be a problem here. Kinect Studio data collection is extremely resource-intensive and it may not be possible to do real-time video compression while maintaining 25fps. Depending on the network infrastructure available you might be able to offload the RGB data to another machine to compress and store, but this would need to be well tested. This is likely to be a lot of work.

I'd suggest that you first see whether switching to another high-spec machine, with a fast SSD drive and good CPU and GPU, makes the buffering issue go away. If this is the case you could then record using Kinect Studio and then post-process the XEF files after the sessions to compress the videos (using the Kinect Studio APIs to open the XEF files).

Comment: Hi John, I noticed that you mentioned to "post-process the XEF files after the recording sessions using Kinect Studio APIs", would you please give a more specific hint, like, which API to use to open an XEF file? Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific! I was referring to replaying the XEFs to simulate the sensor while your app (or another app) processes the data using the normal Kinect APIs to read frames and do whatever it needs to do.

You can either trigger playback of an XEF file interactively using Kinect Studio, or (apparently) using the APIs I linked in my answer. I haven't tried this latter approach yet though.

From your application's perspective, the incoming sensor data would be the same as if it was coming from the sensor in real time, so you can process it accordingly.